# Why an application working in Windows7(.net 3.5)is not working in Win8(.net4.5)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8

i have an application with TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5

```
 <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Application is working fine in windows 7 but in windows 8 i need to install .net framework 3.5
to use the application.Why i should install .net framework 3.5 even when Win8 have a default .net framework 4.5.What should i do to use the application in both  Win7 and in Win8?

Comment: I guess this would help http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-8/install-net-framework-3-5-3-0-2-0-on-windows-8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 3.5 is not installed on Windows 8 by default, only .NET 4.5.

.NET 4.0/4.5 and .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 are side-by-side installations. As such, applications built on .NET 3.5 will not run on 4.0 or 4.5. See [this MSDN article for more information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb822049.aspx)

See [this MSDN article about installing .NET 3.5 on Windows 8.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh506443.aspx)

Comment: is there any way to update my application to use 3.5 in Win7 and 4.5 in Win8

Comment: No, you would have to have 2 separate versions of the application. One compiled against .NET 3.5 and one compiled against .NET 4.5. If possible, I would just install .NET 3.5 on Windows 8.

Comment: how can i create a new version in .net 4.5 by updating my current .net 3.5 application.What properties should i change

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx) for a summary of which versions of .NET are preinstalled on each version of Windows.

Unfortunately, there is no common version preinstalled on both Windows 7 and Windows 8. Windows 7 comes with 3.5.1 (includes 2.0, 3.0, 3.5) and Windows 8 comes with 4.5.